# How to use an ASY2400 Xenon Flash Unit

Tags: schematics, high-voltage, diagram

Background:
I just picked up an ASY2400 Xenon Flasher unit from a local electronics store. I found this hookup diagram for it: [image: Hookup Diagram]

I connected a potential difference of 12V to the board. +12V to pin J4 and 0V to pin J1. When I press the power button it makes a humming sound; however, the U shape Xenon tube is not flashing.

Question:

Pin J1 and J2 are labeled -12V and J4 is labeled 12V does this mean that I should connected a potential difference of 24V (0V to J1 and 24V to J4)?

I was not able to find a more detailed spec sheet. Does anyone have any idea what pins J5, J3, and J6 are used for?

Update: Thanks for your continued help, but several months ago I got rid of this board.

Comment: You have to get Q1 to switch 12v through T1 to generate H.V. Maybe T1 secondary and D3 + C2 with Q1 form a free-running oscillator?

Comment: You might find more info if you sesrch for the part number pittco067.  I find many more sites for that than asy2400.  These are definitely your device as the pictures shown are also marked with both asy2400 and pittco067.  No datasheet so far, though.

Comment: [Like here](http://www.shaogood.com/shaogood/ebay/121555242756.html) This shows your board, but the connections are labeled more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can almost work out the circuit from the photograph, since the PCB traces are fairly visible through the substrate.

The circuitry to the left of the power switch generates the high-voltage to charge the flash capacitor C3 at the top. The circuitry to the right of the power switch provides the trigger pulses to the trigger transformer T2.

There's a diode between J5 and J4 — it looks like the intent is that you connect an external power supply to J5 and J1, and then hook a battery between J4 and J2. This allows the external supply to charge the battery.

J3 and J6 are a little less clear. If I had to guess, I'd say that J3 is another ground connection. You can verify this by looking at the other side of the board. J6 looks like it's connected to the high-voltage bus, perhaps through a resistor, so perhaps it is meant for monitoring the voltage in some way.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason why it fails: The main transformer core is broken mechanically. That could be the reason why it's humming, too.

Check the big capacitator on top. When the transformer is okay it's charged at about 300V.

**DO NOT TOUCH ITS TERMINALS** as it has plenty of charge. Could get you a heart stroke. It even may stay charged when power is off, depending how lousy the circuit was designed.

So, wire your DMM to it, then turn the 12V power on. Look at the DMM display but stay away from the circuit for a while even when you removed the 12V power.

When you're still good, come back for next step.

Comment: Thanks for your help and emphasis on safety, but I ended up getting rid of the circuit months ago.

Comment: Thought so, but there are people googling these questions and nobody pointed out how dangerous these flashers are. Because no one expects to be electrocuted by a 12V circuit.